# Assigning variable to firestore value check

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am trying to assign `bm_array` to my firestore array (if it exists, else an empty array).
The logic is to check for a firestore's document whose name is the current user firebase uid. I am able to console.log my intended array(at line 12), however the `bm_array` returns `null` (at line 25) before the actual array is assigned to `bm_array`. I tried using async but the bm_array either return a promise object or null. I am not sure how to use async.

```
var bm_array = null;
const getBookmarks = async() => {
  var firestore = firebase.firestore();
  var userBookmarks = firestore.collection("userBookmarks");
  await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      await userBookmarks.doc(user.uid).get().then(async function(doc){
        if (doc.exists){
          bm_array = await doc.data().countries;
          console.log(bm_array);
        }else{
          bm_array = [];
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
    } else {
      return []
    }
  });
 }
 getBookmarks();
 console.log(bm_array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) "adds an observer for changes to the user's sign-in state". So it is **constantly** observing if the user's sign-in state is changing.

Since you want to execute your business logic by calling a function, you should better use the `currentUser` property to get the user value.

Something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
  const getBookmarks = async () => {
    var firestore = firebase.firestore();
    var userBookmarks = firestore.collection('userBookmarks');
    
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
    if (user) {
        const docSnapshot = await userBookmarks
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get();
          // Note that you need to use await only in the above line, since it is the only asynchronous operation in your async function              

          if (docSnapshot.exists) {
              bm_array = docSnapshot.data().countries;
          } else {
              bm_array = [];
          }
      } else {
          // Not sure you should return anything here,
          // since you just call the function as getBookmarks(); without using the potential returned value
          // Note that you don't return anything when user is not undefined, i.e. in the first part of the if block, above
        return [];
      }
    
  };
```